# Wake laptop on lan via wireless printer?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, printer, wake-on-lan, forwarding

I know how ridiculous this sounds, but I am curious if it would be possible. Basically, I have a laptop that I would like to wake on lan, but I dont want to have to run a cable through my house. There is however a wireless printer nearby.

Does anyone know if it would be possible to connect the laptop to the printer with an ethernet cable, and then send a packet to the printer, to be passed to the laptop, which will then wake it?

I know this is a very odd and clunky idea, but as I said, curiosity.

Many thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. In a laptop-printer relationship, the laptop is the "master" - i.e. it initiates  communication with the printer via the driver. It only "listens" to the printer (and by that, I mean polls it - again through the driver) to be appraised of jobs' progress, and/or problems. Since it needs the driver to operate that connection, it needs to be awake.

One suggestion, if that's an issue you want to hack: get one of those cheap, sub $20 wi-fi mini-routers, that can also be configured as bridge/hub. Connect to your laptop, and ping its IP remotely to wake up your laptop.

Comment: Cannot believe the idea of getting a little booster type thing never came to mind. Thanks so much for this. Has saved an awful lot of faf :)